# How to set multiple controls at the same place?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an image button and three other buttons .
When the page is loaded only the image button is visible and the other three buttons are hidden.
When the user clicks on the image button, the image button should be hidden and the other three buttons should be visible.

I want to do this activity at the same place.
How can I solve this problem with javascript?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this using javascript, for image button's onclickclick use a JS function to hide that image button itself and show rest 3  buttons.Just make sure that 3 button is hidden by style="display:none" not by visible = false in code -- this will make control unavailable in aspx,

imagebutton's onclientclick="ToggleElement(this)";, and assuming you have jquery reference.

js function would be like the following

```
function ToggleElement(element)
{
$(element).hide();
$("selector_for_3 buttons").show();
}
```